# How to assign output of Grep in a Variable

Tags: linux, shell-script, grep, variable

I am trying to assign the output of `grep` in a variable .
The below command provide me the correct output in a script

`str="DWMessStage-20230609-083501.xml__a6e27c1.4a73a37b.13.1889d3efa14.N7f9d.stage"`

```
echo $str  | grep "__"  | tr -s "__" | tr -s "__" | cut -d "_" -f1

Output : DWMessStage-20230609-083501.xml
```

Now instead of `echo` I want to assign the output in a variable .

I have tried below

`varfilname=$(str  | grep "__"  | tr -s "__" | tr -s "__" | cut -d "_" -f1)`

`varfilname=$($str  | grep "__"  | tr -s "__" | tr -s "__" | cut -d "_" -f1)`

`varfilname="$str  | grep "__"  | tr -s "__" | tr -s "__" | cut -d "_" -f1"`

None of that work . How to assign it in a variable

Comment: Hello Shuvra. It seems like you are overcomplicating things. If `str` holds the string you have in your question then `new_string="${str%%__*}"`  is what you want. When you `echo "$new_string"`  you'll see `DWMessStage-20230609-083501.xml`

Answer (score 0):

`varfilname=$(echo $str | grep "__"  | tr -s "__" | tr -s "__" | cut -d "_" -f1)`

This worked for me